# Android Camera2 getPreviewFrame

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to get the camera frame in preview mode. I am running the sample project from github https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

The issue I am having is getting the frame in preview mode.

Here is the code:

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    private void process(CaptureResult result) {
        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW: {

                //HERE, HOW CAN I RETRIEVE THE CURRENT FRAME?

                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_LOCK: {
               ...
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE: {
             ...
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE: {
             ...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Another thing I tried to get the frame is setting the  mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener.
I was expecting to be able to get the frame onImageAvailable callback, but onImageAvailable is never called. onPreviewFrame is my own method, I need to pass it the current frame.

```
  mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
  mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

  private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener  = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        mTextureView.onPreviewFrame(reader.acquireNextImage().getPlanes([0].getBuffer().array());
    }

};
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `OnImageAvailableListener.onImageAvailable` callback is never called when a preview frame is available because the `CaptureRequest` which was sent to the `CameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest()` method did not list the `ImageReader`'s `Surface` as an output target.

You identify what output `Surface`s (raw byte buffers, essentially) you want the data of each capture to go to when you send the request to the camera. So to get the "preview frames" to trigger the `onImageAvailable()` callback and then be sent to your `onPreviewFrame()` method, simply add the line:

`mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());`

This line can go, *e.g*., after the other similar line that adds the `SurfaceTexture`'s `Surface` to the same request builder.

Note that this will send every preview frame to your function, as well as the "output frames" from the capture button. You may want some code in the `onImageAvailable()` callback to discriminate.

Comment: Hello @Summer, do you know any method in which I can grab the frame on the process method? thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the process() method in mCaptureCallback? The answer is no- the only thing sent there is the CaptureResult metadata ABOUT the image. The Image itself is sent wherever you added as a target to the corresponding CaptureRequest. But basically the original question asked above is essentially what you are hoping to do, I think... register an ImageReader's Surface as the output of a request and then listen for the outputs to appear with an OnImageAvailableListener().

Comment: Unfortunately, I also have similar problem and I failed to solve it with the above answer. Do I need to create a new CaptureRequest? (in the sample there is one for the Preview, can I reuse it and just add target to it?

Comment: Following the instructions provided in the answer my app freezes, even after discriminating against most frames that come to the imageAvailableListener. How have you guys managed to solve this problem? Adding the surface for a set amount of time and then removing it?

Comment: To avoid this issue, you should use getBitmap() on the TextureView attached to the camera. Then your filter would go to the captureCallback, so you don't overwhelm the device. Cheers for the informative question and answers guys.

Comment: @Sipty I have same problem. When I add mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface()); it freezes the preview. Could you explain a bit more. Thanks

Comment: Hey @user1154390. To get an image from the preview, just call frame = textureView.getBitmap(width, height);, that's the fastest and most efficient way I found. Syncing it is a different issue, but to put it simply, make sure your preview is active. Note -- some times in the beginning, you will get a black image, in this case we've found that just recalling the frame fetch is the safest way.  Let me know if this was helpful to you.

Comment: @Sipty Thanks, I need raw frame data like onFramePreview Camera Api level one

Comment: I haven't worked much with api1; If you need raw frame data, you will need to update the captureSession to produce a format RAW_SENSOR for a frame and then retrieve it as an Image and finally process it. It's pretty long and convoluted, I have to admit, but it works here, hope it will for you too. :-)

Comment: mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
already in my code but onImageAvailable listener never get called