# callback for each frame captured from camera on android

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I found a project using `opencv` or something of the sorts to send video frame-by-frame for streaming purposes.

Unfortunately for me, newer examples which use `camera2` rather than the deprecated `Camera` are very scarce. The simplest example I could find was by google, <s>but it seemed to only record - I didn't find anything that seemed like a callback for each captured frame.</s> but it uses a Fragment to request permissions, which I'm hoping I can avoid using, since Fragments seem to complicate things unnecessarily.

All I need is to set up a background process, and somehow use the camera to "record" video, minus the actual recording - once I have something that invokes the `OnImageAvailableListener`, I intend on sending the frames to my computer via USB with AOA, not save it to the phone.

I managed to figure out how to choose the size, format, and other parameters, but what I haven't managed to understand is what exactly is it that I need to do to actually have the listener invoked once I get permissions.

Similar questions have been asked here, but I have yet to find an example using the new camera API.

Comment: possible duplicate: *[Android Camera2 getPreviewFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195940/android-camera2-getpreviewframe)*

Comment: @AlexCohn I wish. but it does seem to have useful information.